Framer replaced damaged studs in shower with new studs. But plans to use furring strips over notches he made for the pipes
A framer replaced damaged studs where my shower was.  But instead of cutting/capping the existing pipes and letting the plumber drill holes, he cut 2” deep notches into the new studs, placed them behind/pipes into the notches and plans to use furring strips once the plumber is finished.  Is this reasonable?



Maybe.  Are the studs 2x4s or 2x6s?  With a non loading bearing wall, studs are not much more than a nice place to screw drywall on.  You usually do not want a plumber doing framing and a framer doing plumbing.  Two different jobs with two different codes to obey.

Thanks.  It’s an outside wall, so yes load bearing wall.  2x4.  The original plan was for the framer to cut off the water, cut the pipe and use a sharkbite to cap it until the plumber could finish the work.

In a non load bearing wall, this sounds like no problem.  I'm impressed that the framer agreed to come back and do furring strips .

Please post photos

They are doing two bathroom remodels for me so they have incentive.  I was surprised that the “sharkbite” work planned for today changed to the notch/furring plan done today.  (It was a termite issue discovered during the demo work.  Terminix has to sign off before the project proceeds any further.)

Thanks Rohit.  Not home right now but will post photos in a few hours.

A wall that roof rafters/trusts sit on is load bearing.  The end walls not so much.  Water pipes in outside walls is usually not the best idea in cold areas(not Florida).  Should only be done if no choice or take precautions against freezing.  2 inch notch in a 2x4 is iffy if load bearing.

A gable-end wall may be load bearing, it depends on the roof construction, eg stick-built.

Hip.  Against the front wall.  The one with the notched studs is the side.  Raised eyebrow regardless.  Bottom line question is that with the furring strip, is it at least as robust as if the plumber drilled a hole and there was no strip.

Pictures added at the top.

I don't understand what's happening at the jack/king studs where the pipes are.

I think this is fine. But if you are worried, you can ask the framer to install some stud shoes.
https://www.strongtie.com/miscellaneousconnectors_woodconnectors/ss_studshoe/p/ss

Sure, but based on the amount of notching, the studs may need additional notching for shoes to fit.
